# Find out last login time in hours

Tags: laravel

Hello here is i am trying to do is to find out last login time of users in hours and want to find out the difference of current time and last login time in Api. 
The response i am getting is

{
    "status": "true",
    "message": "Last Login Time Appeared Successfully!",
    "dataArray": [
        {
            "Lastlogin": "2016-05-31 23:06:39"
        }
]
}
and response i want to get is

lastLoginTime": "48 Hours",

and my Controller Code is

$id = $request->input('id');

```
    $user = DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->select('users.Lastlogin')
        ->get();
    if($user)
    {
        $resultArray = ['status' => 'true', 'message' => 'Last Login Time Appeared Successfully!', 'dataArray' => $user];
        return Response::json($resultArray, 200);
    }
    else{
        $resultArray = ['status' => 'false', 'message' => 'Not Find Last Login Time!'];
        return Response::json( $resultArray, 400);
    }
```

Any help will be appreciatd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate hour using Carbon,like that

```
$user = DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->select('users.Lastlogin')
        ->get();
    if($user)
    {
        $lastLogin = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->Lastlogin);
        $current = \Carbon\Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $diffInHour = $current->diffInHours($lastLogin);

        $resultArray = ['status' => 'true', 'message' => 'Last Login Time Appeared Successfully!', 'dataArray' => $user];
        $resultArray['dataArray']['lastLoginTime'] = $diffInHour.'hours';
        return Response::json($resultArray, 200);
    }
    else{
        $resultArray = ['status' => 'false', 'message' => 'Not Find Last Login Time!'];
        return Response::json( $resultArray, 400);
    }
```

Comment: Now my reponse is    {
    "status": "true",
    "message": "Last Login Time Appeared Successfully!",
    "dataArray": {
        "lastLoginTime": 38
    }
}

Comment: how i can convert 38 into 38 hours and into proper json format single quotes?